# Should we move 'votes' to 'All actions'?

Tags: discussion, design, activity-tab

Votes are part of 'All actions' that a user can take... so logically you should be able to find them when you look in 'All actions'.

> [image]

I am not sure if I am the only one, but many a times I have gone looking for some question that I close voted and I spend a lot of time in the 'All actions' tab or trying to look in the 'helpful flags' list only to realize that there is a dedicated tab for 'votes'.

Comment: A possible downside of this is that with the current design, users may not be able to filter by vote type anymore and has to browse through pagination manually.

Comment: @AndrewT. true, I didn't think about that 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions and Answers are also *"part of 'All actions' that a user can take"*...

I don't see why "All actions" would need to be *more* cluttered than it already is.

Now, if we **should** aside, I don't even think it's possible to properly move that into "all actions", as there are a lot of filters on the "votes" page:

[image]

I don't see where you'd put those buttons on the more generic "all actions" page.

Furthermore, the "All actions" page is public, and "Votes" is private. I imagine it's easier to hide a page like that, than to hide a single action type.

Comment: Q&A are also part of a user's 'all actions' but I see them as being the most important parts of a Q&A platform so I can see how putting them outside makes sense... votes on the other hand don't seem that important that they need a seperate section outside the 'All actions' tab... but I didn't think about the filters available in 'Votes'... touché... I have changed the question to not be a feature request anymore.